# Task.run() for multitasks runs

Tags: c#, multiprocessing, windows-services

I want to run more than one tasks simultaneous based on a return value.
Below is the rough code for what I want.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void tempFunc(string username,string password, ref Queue<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queue)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                Task.Delay(100000);
                Console.WriteLine(username + i);
            }
            queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(username, password));
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // A queue which is storing the username and password for different sessions and they need
            // to be passed to the method being called in Tasks.run
            Queue<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queue = new Queue<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user1", "password1"));
            queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user2", "password2"));
            queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user3", "password3"));

            while(true)
            {  // Based on the condition mentioned here(this condition is a method in real which returns a list of
               //string, which I will be passing as a parameter to the method being called in Tasks.run but I haven't put that in code here)
               if(condition)
               { 
                   if(queue.Count != 0)
                   {
                       KeyValuePair<string, string> temp = queue.Dequeue();
                       string username = temp.Key;
                       string password = temp.Value;

                       Task.Run(() => tempFunc(username, password, ref queue));
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

Idea is to have a pool of `username`and `password`, when a task is done, it will enqueue the used `username` and `password` so that it can be used again. There can be multiple tasks and they are not dependent on each other i.e. when one task is running other task can use other set of `username` and `password` and call method. and this all is running as a part of `windows service`. 
Issue is when I am using the mentioned code, It seems to be working synchronously. i.e. waiting for one task to be finished and then run other task after that. What am I doing wrong? or I am using `Tasks.run` wrong way.

Comment: If you're going to use a queue in a parallel way, you'll probably want to use `ConcurrentQueue`

Comment: This code has too many compiler errors for me to figure out how you are even able to run it

Comment: I added `condition` intentionally to give the idea. Other than that it gets compiled because I was able to. Where do you think it will not? Sorry, forgot to remove `await` while editing. Removed it now.

Comment: There are too much problems in your code. I guess you are not familiar multithreading and with TPL. Try to read and get information about that topics: **Threads, Tasks, Async/Await, Thread safety, Concurrent collections**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Few changes and your program will start working asynchronously.

The changes I'll recommend are:

A) Change the function `tempFund` to include `aysnc`. And no need to include `queue` as parameter to this function. You can add user back to queue in calling function once task is complete.

```
public static async Task tempFunc(string username, string password)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before work start : {0}", username + i);
        await Task.Delay(2000);  //I have reduced it. OP can use his time
        Console.WriteLine("After work complete : {0}", username + i);
    }
}
```

B) Use `ConcurrentQueue` for thread-safe operations. The same has been suggested by Jones.

```
//Use ConcurrentQueue

var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

C) Modify the if block as:

```
  if (queue.Count != 0)
  {
      var temp = new KeyValuePair<string, string>();
      queue.TryDequeue(out temp);
      string username = temp.Key;
      string password = temp.Value;

      Task.Run(async () =>
      {
          Console.WriteLine("before Task start : {0}", username);
          await tempFunc(username, password);
          Console.WriteLine("after Task Ends : {0}", username);
          queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(username, password));
      });
```

Make a note of additional logs which will make it obvious that program in running asynchronously.

Comment: I read about it a bit after you posted. But I am a little confused the way it works. when I call `await` on the method, the main thread will not wait for the method to return and will continue. but if instead of `await Task.Delay(2000);` I just want some bunch of statements to run how do I do that? because `async` can't be used without `await`.

Comment: An edit- when I call `await` on the method, the main thread will wait till the `await` is encountered in called method and will continue. but if I don't want main thread to wait at all, is the right way to do it to add the delay as `0` instead of `2000` and put that statement in the start of function? because I just want the main thread to carry on after calling the method without waiting at all.

Comment: @sporty_1993 If you call `await` on one method that does not mean `main` thread will wait for it. In your case a new `Task` has been started that calls `tempFunc`. So even new Task will not wait at `await` rather it will become free. Lines after `await` are called like in a `delegate` once `tempFunc` completes. I represented `Task.Delay` as if some work to be done. Any calculation or other work you want to do then remove `Task.Delay` and add new lines.

Comment: If I don't put `Task.Delay` and replace ` await Task.Delay(2000); ` with actual logic, then compiler shows that `await` should be there with `async` , now how do I remove `await`?

Comment: Depends. If you want to replace `Task.Delay` with another function then that function declaration should include `async` and `await` should be kept as well. But if you want to replace `Task.Delay` with a `while-loop` or `for-loop` or a block of statement then `await` is not needed.

Comment: But without `await` it throws compiler error  that `async` can't be used without `await`